# C++ output operator overload

Tags: c++, generics, overloading

I've been working on this school assignment. The assignment told us to make an object which had it's output operator ( << ) overloaded.
Here's my code:

```
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class CustomObject {

        string print() {
            string text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < num_items(); i++) {
                text += queue[i];
                text += " | \n";
            }
            return text;
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &output, CustomObject &q) {
            output << "" << q.print();
            return output;
        }
}
```

So I instantiate this object like this:

```
CustomObject<int> co();
```

and call its output method:

```
std::cout << co();
```

Which would inevitably call the print method, and return the string to the default output stream.

But, there's no visible output in my console/debugger.

What am I missing here?

PS this is **not** the complete class, it's generic because of several other methods and functionality that is not necessary to be shown here.

PPS the num_items() and queue variables are part of said rest, this class is a PriorityQueue object. So, queue is an array of the specified type (hence the generic declaration) and num_items() just returns the count of the array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CustomObject<int> co();
```

That's a function declaration. Leave out the parenthesis.

```
std::cout << co();
```

Why are you appling `operator()` to `co`? Again, leave out the parenthesis. This should work:

```
CustomObject<int> co;
std::cout << co;
```

Alas, building and returning a string from a print method is hardly idiomatic C++. Here is what I would do:

```
template <typename T>
class CustomObject
{
    // ...

public:

    void print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        for (int i = 0; i != num_items(); ++i)
        {
            os << queue[i] << " | \n";
        }
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CustomObject& object)
{
    object.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: I assume he's applying the function call operator, because `co` is a function, and the compiler complained until he added the parens.  Of course, linking should have failed because `co` has no definition, just a declaration.  And compiling should have failed because, as @Bo pointed out, the `operator<<` took a non-const reference, which can't bind a temporary.  So what actual code was being tested is anyone's guess.

Comment: The parenthesis where used for the constructor method of my custom class. Or is that not the correct way to call my object's constructor method?

Comment: Pretty unsure from what the problem was to the working code, It works.
can you please point out what the problem was? I'm still using the parenthesis in the creation of my object, which calls it's constructor from what I can see in my debugger. Is there a 'valid' way of doing such things, like e.g. objective c?
And, what practical use is here for using the const flag, I know what it does and such, but I thought my code logic would leave out the necessity to use 'const'... :D

Thanks though, works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to print temporary objects a well, you should make the parameter a const reference:

```
CustomObject const& q)
```